# Why the photomultiplier experiment proves that photon is a particle, not a wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, wave-particle-duality

In QED Feynman describes the photomultiplier experiment as a proof that a photon behaves as a particle. The logic is as follows: with monochromatic single photon light source a photomultiplier coupled with a speaker is either silent or responds with sounds of the same loudness. Hence light is a particle which either hits the multipliers plate or not.

However,the multiplier's action is based on the electrons, which are particles. Why there cannot be an alternative explanation, that light is a wave, whose energy either suffices to knock out a single electron,that initiates the cascade, or does not and in that case the photomultiplier remains silent.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long comment on the discussion in comments:

> I would not expect Mr. Feynman to make silly mistakes in his books, so I'm really looking for counter-arguments to my question. –

It is not a mistake, because if one puts down the photoelectric effect etc, this is what happens, and so it could just be that he had in mind an argument that is not explicitly stated.

Talking of mistakes and Feynman :

I have been lucky to be at summer schools and workshops where Feynman took part,
So I want to share a story I have written elsewhere before that shows that even giants in physics can be wrong at times.

> This story is in the 1980s, after Feynman had his first operations and when he was feeling well enough to go to conferences, in Crete, at a theoretical workshop. It is the second day he is in Greece, the first being spent going around the “must sees” of Athens with yours truly, so definitely jet lagged.

> It is after sunset, and many eminent physicists are having a drink on a veranda overlooking the Aegean, and several Greek ones from other disciplines attracted by the pole of Feynman (as yours truly).

> There is small talk and a lull in conversation and suddenly the full moon draws the attention on the horizon in all its glory, reflected in the waters. Feynman looks and observes: ” that must be the West then”.

> The interest in the story is not the slip of Feynman, it is the reaction of the physicists. Feynman said it after all, so that must be the west. I do not remember if t’Hooft was there at the time, he sure was at the workshop. It remained for yours truly, youngest and most irrelevant in the company to sputter: “but,but, but….”.

Answer (score 2):

This experiment is very similar (if not analogous) to the photoelectric  effect which also proves light having particle features. Explanation goes like this.
In classical physics electromagnetic light wave intensity (or also carried light energy defined by Poynting vector) :
$$ \tag 1 I,|\vec S| \propto ~E_0 \cdot B_0 $$

So classically, to knock-out a single electron in the photomultiplier and to produce cascade event, it would be enough to raise light intensity to the levels needed to produce speaker sound connected to the photo-multiplier. So grab a high intensity, but *low frequency* laser, like operating in FIR (far infra-red range) and shine with it into photomultiplier. No sound. Why ?
**Classical EM wave theory fails here,- it is unable to explain WHY**.

When we take into account quantum mechanics, it says that actually electron is escaping it's environment, not because it absorbs  EM wave classically, but because it is bombarded with photon (light particle) which has intrinsic energy $$\tag 2 E=h\nu$$.

Now this can explain why FIR laser light is not enough to produce sound in speaker. Because FIR laser photon does not pass required frequency threshold to free electron from photomultiplier as per (2) equation. So to say $h\nu \lt W$ for FIR photon, where $W$ is electron ionization energy in photosensitive material.
Of course there is non-linear effects too when very high light intensities also frees additional electrons compared to base electron out-flow, but basic law is that one dictated in (2).

Comment: Yes, your notes are correct, sorry for bad English and typo's. Fixed.

Comment: Classical physics knows about resonance and energy thresholds, so this story about classical EM theory failing, although widespread, is oversimplified and hasty.

Comment: Yes, it knows about resonance frequencies, but it does not relate resonance frequencies to quanta energy with proportionality factor $h$, it was done only by Planck, which together with Einstein (photoelectric effect description) has made pre-cursors to QM. And I'm not quite sure if Planck relation (2) has anything to do exactly with resonance frequencies, cause up the $\nu_{0}$ ladder there can be many (if not infinite amount) of frequency harmonics which can initiate electron firing effect. So topic is not about "one or few special frequencies" which classical resonance theory speaks about.

Answer (score 0):

Term *photomultiplier* refers more to the principle of detection than to what we count, which is the central point of the question here. In this respect it is better to differentiate between a *single-photon detector* and a *photon counter*, which are doing somewhat different job (although the former is usually a part of the latter).

*Single photon detection* is not the same as *photon counting*. The counting error typically increases as $$\sigma_n\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ where $n$ is the number of photons detected. Thus, indeed, detecting with certainty presence of a single photon is nearly impossible. However, detecting the arrival of the 1001th photon after we counted a thousand of them can be done with high precision.

Comment: here the term photomultiplier refers to a particular type of device used to detect single photons and it is the term used by Feynman in his book. Could you please elaborate how exactly the discussion of counting error contributes to the question of whether we can conclude that a photon is a particle on the basis of the electrostatic photomultiplier experiment.

Comment: @DanielKislyuk Do you agree that being countable is a particle-like property? Waves, on the other hand, have continuous amplitude and intensity.

Comment: I do agree. My argument is that since electrostatic photomultiplier functioning is based on particles it can quantize the wave input and it is impossible to conclude on the basis of this particular experiment, whether photon is a particle or a wave.

Comment: @DanielKislyuk I think this is actually the point: that one photon produces exactly one electron, i.e., that the output is quantized. How would you get the same outcome with a continuous wave?

Comment: If those photons as waves had energies at the level sufficient to knock out one electron, slightly below and slightly above, the result would have been exactly the same,  wouldn't it?

Comment: If we consider the semi-classical absorption of light, then the energy and the frequency are not the same thing. Even more, an EM wave does not have a finite energy, but characterized by an energy density. I suppose that one could try to develop a theory of how an eletromagnetic wave is attenuated by single-electron excitations... but it is not at all obvious that one can obtain energy conservation there.